Multiple Db connection with Dapper
I have a situation in my project to use multiple db connections with Dapper.
I have created an abstract class  with constructor to pass a connections
here is example
public abstract class BaseRepository 
{

private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;
public BaseRepository(IDbConnection dbConnection)
{
    
    _dbConnection = dbConnection;
}

    public async Task<int> ExecuteAsync(string sql, object? param = null, 
                   IDbTransaction? 
                   transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? 
                   commandType = null)
  {

    try
    {
        return await _dbConnection.ExecuteAsync(sql, param, transaction, 
             commandTimeout, commandType)
                                           .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception, rethrow it, or handle it in some other way
        throw new Exception("An error occurred while retrieving the company.", ex);
    }

   }
  }

and inherited in other class like this
public class PRepository:BaseRepository
 {

public PRepository([FromKeyedServices(DbConnectionKeys.PCMRead)] IDbConnection 
  _connectionP, 
   ) : base(_connectionP)
{ 
}

   }

I just want to know is it the right way to do this or any other way to achieve the same without abstract .
Thanks in advance

I can't see the point of this. If I wanted multiple connections with dapper I would just make multiple connections and use them. With this approach you seem to have to implement proxy methods on your classes that call the same signatures extensions dapper provides; why do it? What problem does this structure solve?

@flackoverstow i want a common place to  call db functions . for ex if  I want to add some retry mechanism on db connection . rather write some line of code again and again in all the services . i have created a proxy method there I can add the mechanism  and something more  in future as well .

If there was stuff I wanted to do to every db connection before I used it I'd probably have a factory that manufactured my setup connection before it gave it to me, and inject that everywhere. Your question might need an opinion based answer, alas. If I wanted to selectively do something to connections I'd look at extension methods. I'd aim to avoid inheritance and also avoid proxying everything in dapper

I also planned it through the extension method. but the problem is I have some dependencies to resolve that is not possible in the extension method.  abstract class is an alternative for connection factory and rather passing parameter to factory to decide on connection . i can directly call the child  class  functions with current approach

@user2797910 Are you trying to access different databases which have different connectionStrings through dapper ?

@SM yes  i have different dapper connections

@user2797910 Dapper doesn't have its own connections. IDbConnection is an ADO.NET class. What you ask is already available. The problem is the class design, not Dapper or ADO.NET. In fact, your ExecuteAsync is identical to the Dapper method, offering no benefit at all

Connections are meant to be short lived, because any locks or DB resources used remain taken until either the connection or the transaction completes. If you want to use different connections, inject the connection strings and create the connections at the last possible moment. If you don't want to get tied to a specific class like SqlConnection or NpgSqlConnection, use ADO.NET's DbProviderFactory

Check out if this helps. I have created a file called DapperContext.cs in my WebAPI Project. In my case, even I have to access multiple Databases. Here is what I have done inside DapperContext.cs :
public class DapperContext
{
    private readonly string _databaseConnectionString1; 
    private readonly string _databaseConnectionString2;

    public DapperContext(string databaseConnectionString1,string databaseConnectionString2)
    {
        _databaseConnectionString1= databaseConnectionString1;
        _databaseConnectionString2= databaseConnectionString2;
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateConnection() => new SqlConnection(_databaseConnectionString1);
    public IDbConnection CreateLogConnection() => new SqlConnection(_databaseConnectionString2);

}

Then inside Program.cs, read the connection string from appsettings.json:
var db1string = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db1string");
var db2string = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db2string");

And finally in your code, based on you condition you have handle it like this :
using (var connection = _context.CreateConnection()) // Or _context.CreateLogConnection
{
   // Perfrom Operations.
}

